# How to pass a test if expect fails

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, chai

I have this code

```
it('This should pass anyway', function (done) {
  testObj.testIt(regStr);
});
```

testObj

```
this.testIt = function (regStr) {
  selector.count().then(function (orgCount) {
    for (var curr = 0; curr < count; curr++) {
       checkField(curr, regStr);
    }
  });
};

function checkField(curr, regStr) {
  selector.get(curr).all(by.tagName('li')).get(0).getInnerHtml().then(function (text) {
    expect(text).to.match(regStr, curr + '#ERR');
  });
}
```

If one of these expects get a failure, test fails. How can i handle this? I mean - can i somehow count passed and failed expect()ations and return it? or, at least, dont let test break on first error.

I've tried try-catch, but nothing good happened.

```
it('This should pass anyway', function (done) {
  try {
    testObj.testIt(regStr);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('#err' + e);
  }
});
```

And then i wanted to use done(), but havent found any examples to do the similar. Can u please help me?
Sry for my english

UPD

Comment: Can you share what kind of for loop is it? What are you iterating over?

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. Are you wanting the test to pass even though an expectation fails? If so, then that's not really an expectation. You should not use expect() unless you have an expectation. If this is the case, you should be keeping a count and only failing at the end of the test if the count is bad.

Comment: Yes. i want to handle strings, that arent match my regexp. Now i can see only one per it, then test fails.

Comment: Or i really need to skip expect and use if to match strings? And then expect a count of passed strings to be equal to all strings tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return either null or a string from checkField(), join them up, and expect the array to be empty:

```
this.testIt = function (regStr) {
  selector.count().then(function (orgCount) {
    var errors = [];
    for (var curr = 0; curr < orgCount; curr++) {
       var e = checkField(curr, regStr);
       if (e) { errors.push(e); }
    }
    assert.equal(0, errors.length, errors);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach would be to use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) to collect the data into an array:

```
var data = selector.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.element(by.tagName('li')).getText();
});

expect(data).toEqual(["test1", "test2", "test3"]);
```